# Sending an Interative form inside email

Tags: java, php, .net, email

Is is possible to send any form inside an email, which recipient can fill in and hit enter to submit the form?

Preferably we are looking for outlook clients, so form must open inside outlook emails and can be replied via email or form submission.

Form will contain 5-6 fields like input, select, radio?

Last option will be an hosted cloud server to view the html form inside email and and its submit goes to cloud server? Does this work?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.  Most email clients (Outlook included) disable forms inside an email as a safety measure.  The best solution would be to have a link (text, image, etc.) inside the email that opens a webpage containing the form.

Comment: Can't we even think of HTML forms? Or something like how the VOTE Option works inside outlook????